# Is boost spirit a good fit for this situation?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, hdf5

I've got a situation where I'm trying to build up an HDF compound type out from a stream of name-value pairs (for simplicity's sake, we'll say that a value can be either a double or a character string). Just to be clear, the numeric data is already binary - it's not a string. The names provide structural information (is this part of an array?, is this part of a nested compound type?).

I'm imagining making a vector of tokens, using the name information to insert tokens (e.g. '[' and ']' to delimit an array, '{' and '}' to delimit nested compounds), but otherwise using the values.  It's not clear to me from the documentation if the Spirit binary parsers would be an appropriate choice to handle the numeric values.

Comment: Based on my limited experience (2 weeks of research) if you have no experience with it, everything else is a better choice. It is very hard to start writing with boost spirit, the resulted code is extremely slow to compile. The elegance of the code at the end is not worth the journey. Else if you are careful how to ask you may expect to receive help on this site. There are several guys with a lot of experience that will jump on every question you have (be ready to be patronized, though)

Comment: It sounds to me like most of the work is going to be sorting out your exact encoding protocol and data structures... the parsing can as easily be done with a std::stream and read(), a few if and while statements....

Comment: @TonyD You're making the same mistake as everyone: "text" is not trivial anywhere in computing. Think Unicode. Think INF, negative INF, NaN, think exponents, think (arbitrary) precision, (in)significant whitespace... It's best to have the requirements clear before embarking. To the OP: Spirit is useful here, but you will have to learn stuff, as gsf warns

Comment: @sehe I was pretty far down the path of writing an ad hoc parser, and took a step back to explore alternatives. Spirit looks pretty interesting, but my token stream is a little off-beat - the numeric data has already been converted.  If I end up with even uglier ad-hoc shim code to interact with Spirit, I'll feel pretty silly. So I'm doing a little sanity-check by asking here.

Comment: @user888379 Okay, I'm not going to attempt to Oracle what is appropriate here (I'm not convinced you would want to use Spirit here). Regardless, I posted an answer that shows how Spirit could handle raw binary float in the input.

Comment: @sehe: believe it or not, I've done this often enough in spirit and hand-coded - and supported my own and others' similar code over many years - to have an opinion.  In many cases you either know you're dealing in ASCII text or already have wide-character support, can easily choose length prefixes or suitable delimiters, the question states the numbers are already in binary so there's no inf/NaN issues to handle, and as we're talking about a binary stream it's probably realistic to decide it won't handle ad-hoc whitespace, or to define specific places it's allowed.

Comment: @TonyD Have you ever used Spirit to parse full binary streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't judge whether "the rest" (i.e. the non-binary data) justifies going for a PEG parser generator.

However, just to give you something to start with:

Use

- `qi::bin_float`, `qi::little_bin_float` or `qi::big_bin_float`
- `qi::bin_double`, `qi::little_bin_double` or `qi::big_bin_double`

Here's a 17-line sample program that exactly duplicates the behaviour of

```
od -w8 -A none -t f8 -v input.dat
```

on my box:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    // read file
    ifstream ifs("input.dat", ios::binary);
    string const input { istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {} };

    // parse
    vector<double> result;
    bool ret = qi::parse(begin(input), end(input), *qi::bin_double, result);

    // print
    if (ret) for (auto v : result) 
        cout << setw(28) << setprecision(16) << right << v << "\n";
}
```

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afe3110b53f3ff8e)**

---

Commands used:

```
clang++ -Os -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp          # compile
dd if=/dev/urandom count=32 bs=1 2>/dev/null > input.dat # generate input
./a.out                                               # spirit demo
echo 'And `od` output:'                        
od -w8 -A none -t f8 -v /tmp/input.dat                  # compare to `od`
```

---

**Disclaimer** This just intended in case it helps you see how Spirit handles binary input.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful, and I appreciate your thoroughness.